# Customize cart item removed notice in Woocommerce 3

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product, notice

I am using the WooCommerce 3.4.4 version and I am trying to edit the notice message when you press the "X" button to remove the product from the cart page.

Currently the notice is `"<product name>" removed. Undo?`
I want to remove the quotations and change the message to **`Product name has been removed. [Undo button]`**

I have managed to remove the quotation marks from the product name by writing

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_removed_title', 'removed_from_cart', 10, 2);
function removed_from_cart( $message, $product_data ) {
    $product = get_the_title($product_data['product_id']);
    $message = $product;
    return $message;
}
```

But I am a bit confused on how to do the rest of the edits. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated**

The only available hook is `woocommerce_cart_item_removed_title` that you are using already. and displays the product name between quotes. You can also use `gettex` filter hook to remove the `?` after "Undo" text:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_removed_title', 'removed_from_cart_title', 12, 2);
function removed_from_cart_title( $message, $cart_item ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $cart_item['product_id'] );

    if( $product )
        $message = sprintf( __('Product %s has been'), $product->get_name() );

    return $message;
}

add_filter('gettext', 'cart_undo_translation', 35, 3 );
function cart_undo_translation( $translation, $text, $domain ) {

    if( $text === 'Undo?' ) {
        $translation =  __( 'Undo', $domain );
    }
    return $translation;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> But **you can not change or add `button` tag class** the the `<a>` html tag… 
> **Instead** use the existing `restore-item` tag class **adding some custom CSS styles to it**.

Below some CSS styles example, that you can add to the `styles.css` file of your active child theme:

```css
.woocommerce-message .restore-item, {
    float: right;
    padding: 0 0 0 1em;
    background: 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: none;
    line-height: 1.618;
    border-width: 0 0 0 1px;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-color: rgba(255,255,255,.25)!important;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.woocommerce-message .restore-item:hover {
    background: 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: .8;
}
```

This is what you will get:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to change the question mark after Undo to a period or wrap the entire Undo in a <a href> tag with a button class?

Comment: @user2515606 New code update. It works totally a you expect.